# Cannot use os functions after having imported it

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2015, ironpython

I'm using Python (actually IronPython) with Visual Studio 2015 to make a WPF application. I imported os but I cannot access its methods.

This is what I did:

```
import os

class Utils(object):

    def fcn(self, arg):

        if os.path.exists(arg):
            print 'Exists!.'        
        else:
            print 'Doesn't exist... :/'
            raise
```

I call this class from the view model file after pressing a button in the GUI

```
class ViewModel(ViewModelBase):

    def __init__(self):
        ViewModelBase.__init__(self)
        self.RunCommand = Command(self.RunMethod)
        self.utils = Utils()

    def RunMethod(self):
        self.utils.fcn("C:\path")
```

If I set a breakpoint after "if os.path.exists(arg)" the program freezes, if I set it before (or on that line) it stops normally.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodules need to be imported explicitly:

```
import os.path # not just import os
```

In the standard Python implementation, `import os` would probably work on its own due to the weird way `os.path` is implemented, but it should still be `import os.path` if you want to use `os.path`.